# DBMS_LOB.Compare vs MD5 checksum compare

Tags: oracle, compare, blob, md5

I'm trying to do a comparison of large strings (5,000 - 80,000 characters) between two tables in an oracle DB and simply determine if there are any differences. I plan on converting the strings into BLOBs before storing them and was looking at two methods for doing the comparison.

What would be the likely differences in performance and accuracy using the DBMS_LOB.compare function vs using the MD5 hash function and generating a checksum to compare two BLOBs?

Comment: You can trace it and find out for sure. You might be surprised. I sometimes am.

Answer (score 0):

Just by using the common sense...

**Case 1 – `dbms_lob.compare()` for the first time**

The price is:

1. Read the whole LOB #1.
2. Read the whole LOB #2.

We can neglect the actual comparison, as this is done in memory, while reading the LOBs is done from disk.

The overall price = 2 x reading from disk.

**Case 1 – `dbms_lob.compare()` for subsequent invocations**

The price is:

1. Read the whole LOB #1.
2. Read the whole LOB #2.

We can neglect the actual comparison, as this is done in memory, while reading the LOBs is done from disk.

The overall price = 2 x reading from disk.

**Case 2 – comparing MD5 hashes**

The price is:

1. Read the whole LOB #1, calculate the MD5 from it.
2. Read the whole LOB #2, calculate the MD5 from it.

We can neglect the actual comparison, as this is done in memory, comparing only short sequences of bytes.

Overall price = 2 x reading from disk + 2 x calculating MD5.

I believe that MD5 can be calculated with no visible performance degradation on modern CPUs, hence I suggest neglecting also the calculation of MD5 for the overall price estimation. Hence...

Overall price = 2 x reading from disk.

**Case 2 – comparing MD5 hashes for subsequent invocations**

Assuming your LOBs did not change, hence your precreated and stored MD5 checksums are correct for the non-changed LOBs, the price is... Well, there's no reading of the LOBs from disk; there's merely the comparison of the pre-calculated MD5 checksums, so...

Overall price = constant 1

**Conclusion**

Now you choose what suits you best.

If you need one-time comparisons, use `dbms_lob.compare()`.

However, if you need e.g. comparing each LOB to each LOB (= *n* × *n* comparisons total), then you for sure will be better off with pre-calculating MD5 checksums and comparing the checksums afterwards.